# FMDatabase is currently in use on concurrent execution

Tags: ios, sqlite, salesforce, nsoperation

Am doing preloading the datas from service in my mobile application.

Here I added around 7 service in NSOperationQueue and all these operations result will update the DataBase.

Here while updating the database am getting warning in log like "FMDatabase is currently in use" and datas have not been inserted into DB.

Here how to handle this problem in concurrent execution and updating the database.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't use FMDatabase, but you have to read it's [documentation](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#using-fmdatabasequeue-and-thread-safety)

It is part of the doc:

> So don't instantiate a single FMDatabase object and use it across
>   multiple threads.
>
> Instead, use FMDatabaseQueue. It's your friend and it's here to help.

Comment: +1 @Sergey Demchenko, just to add info. I was calling FMDatabase on background thread using GCD(which creates issue), instead on on main thread( which solves issue).

Comment: I'm getting this error and am using FMDatabaseQueue.